# How to set a default font in gVim?

Tags: vim, fonts

I want to set ***Courier New*** as the default font in Vim.
After browsing through the available fonts (`:set guifont=*`), I found the font ***Courier New*** to be good.

I've put the following in _vimrc file

```
set guifont=Courier New
```

But, I get an error every time I open a new file.

Comment: if you have read the `'gfn'` option help doc,  It was written there clearly: `Setting an option requires an extra
 backslash before a space and a backslash.`

Comment: You can (should?) also set the font size here... `Courier\ New:h9` for example. See `:h E244` (it's a subsection for Windows in the guifont help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the space with a slash:

```
set guifont=Courier\ New
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, I usually recommend to not use `:set`, but rather set the option directly using [VimL](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#:let-&). Options are generally accessible using the `:let &optionname = value`.

There to e.g. add the guifont setting into your .vimrc, simply type this in insert mode

:let &guifont = "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>=&gfn<kbd>Enter</kbd>"<kbd>Esc</kbd>

The advantage is, you can add spaces and backslashes and do not need to escape those special chars. Since this is VimL you only need to quote the setting, since the guioption is a String Option.